# External server html using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am unable to write external HTML using JavaScript.

Can anyone help me using php and JavaScript like this way.

```
<div id="include"></div>
```

in this i want to put HTML from another server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = "SRC='http://demoserver.com/read_files.php?f1=headermenu.html";
document.write ("<script type='text/javascript' "+a+"'>");
document.write("</scr"+"ipt>");
```

here is my php code on my server

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://demoserver.com/headermenu.html';
    $htm = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $htm;
?>
```

and html code is

```
<ul class="menu-link">
<li><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Here are some other options, http://blog.mgechev.com/2011/07/21/ajax-jquery-beginners/.

Comment: when i used Ajax this show Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

Comment: Why not use `<?php include() ?>` in your HTML file and rename it to PHP?

Comment: I thought your PHP was making the request to the remote server? Well if you want to do it client side you'll need JSONP i believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: Hi mouser there is no option for php there is only html

Comment: @chris85  can you please share live example for it .i am unable to do this

Comment: For JSONP or how this would be done with PHP and ajax? I don't use JSONP thats a suggested way I know other developers have gone when trying to achieve this client side, try searching. Im not sure what you mean by "there is no option for php there is only html". You have PHP in your question and tagged.